# How to use data binding when moving the id into the styles file?

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding, android-databinding, android-styles

I have created a style like this:

```
<style name="MyFavoriteViewStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:id">@id/my_favorite_view</item>
</style>
```

As you can see, I have moved the id from the layout file in the Styles.XML file. Doing that, In my activity I get an error:

```
View myFavoriteView = dataBinding.myFavoriteView;
```

Such as `myFavoriteView` is no more recognized. How can I still find that view even if the id is defined in Styles.XML?

Comment: Its a bad idea to keep ids in styles , don't do it

Comment: @ManoharReddy Ok, thanks for your comment. That id is the same across my entire app. So what I'm asking, is it even possible?

Comment: It is possible to use same Id but don't do it , it will make code readability  worse . Always give ids related to what it is and what it does . suppose if there is a TextView which shows a student name give it an id tv_studentName or studentNameTv or textview_studentName or textview_student_name . Choose something you are comfirtable and follow the same naming convention all over app . People will debate over the format but personally I think what ever you are comfortable use it .

Comment: @ManoharReddy I wasn't asking if it's possible to have the same id. I was asking if it's possible to find that view even if the id is defined in the Styles file. What's your opinion?

Comment: I don't think its possible , I am not 100% sure . Even if its possible don't do it .